# Does a square matrix with a null row or column always have a null eigenvalue?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A$ be a real square matrix which contains a null row or a null column. It is true that $A$ has always a null eigenvalue?

Honestly, I don't know how to prove it but I tried to attempts and it seems to me that it is true. Could someone please tell me if the property holds true in general?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try expanding the determinant to get the characteristic polynomial by the row/column of zeros.

Comment: $det(A)=0$ so $0$ is an eigen value.

Comment: When there is a null column, lets say it's the $i$'th column, then the vector with $0$ everywhere except the $i$'th entry which is $1$ is a null eigenvalue.

When there is a null row you can use the fact that the matrix can't have full rank and use the "rank/nullity" theorem, I don't know if there is something more obvious.

Comment: @Yorch More obvious perhaps, if $A$ has, say, first column zero, then $Ae_1=0$, so $0$ is an eigenvalue, for $e_1=(1,0,\ldots ,0)^T$.

Comment: Yeah, I think the case with null row is different as it uses the fact that the transformation is between finite dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: For null row take the transpose $A^T$. Then also $A$ has eigenvalue $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The eigenvalues of a matrix are roots of the characteristic polynomial of the matrix

That is $$ \det (A-\lambda I)=0$$

If $det (A)=0$ then $\lambda=0 $ satisfies the charactristic polynomial so $\lambda =0$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

If $A$ has the $i$-th column $0$, then $A \cdot e_i=0$, where $e_i$ is the column vector $(\delta_{ki})_k$.

If $A$ has a row $0$,  then the system $Ax = 0$ is equivalent to a system of $n-1$ equations with $n$ unknowns. Now, we can show by induction on $n$ (using row reduction) that such a system always has a non-zero solution.

Case II also works if the coefficients are in a non-commutative field, like $\mathbb{H}$.